# Need help installing pyrate for Python on Windows 10, getting error message

Tags: python, raytracing

I need help installing pyrate. I have Windows 10 and installed python 3.9.2 and am trying to install pyrate by following the instructions from:

https://github.com/mess42/pyrate

I have followed the install instructions up until the fourth and final command, which is 'pip install [-e] .'. After entering the command I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 113, in __init__
    req = REQUIREMENT.parseString(requirement_string)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 1955, in parseString
    raise exc
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyparsing.py", line 3814, in parseImpl
    raise ParseException(instring, loc, self.errmsg, self)
pip._vendor.pyparsing.ParseException: Expected stringEnd, found '['  (at char 11), (line:1, col:12)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 189, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 178, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 287, in run
    reqs = self.get_requirements(args, options, finder, session)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 340, in get_requirements
    req_to_add = install_req_from_line(
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\constructors.py", line 391, in install_req_from_line
    parts = parse_req_from_line(name, line_source)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\constructors.py", line 332, in parse_req_from_line
    extras = convert_extras(extras_as_string)
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\constructors.py", line 64, in convert_extras
    return Requirement("placeholder" + extras.lower()).extras
  File "d:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\packaging\requirements.py", line 115, in __init__
    raise InvalidRequirement(
pip._vendor.packaging.requirements.InvalidRequirement: Parse error at "'[-e]'": Expected stringEnd
```

Can someone please help. Thanks.

Comment: what command did you use? did you do use pip?

Comment: ```pip install pyrate``` seems to be working for me

Comment: 'pip install pyrate' another module named pyrate, not the one I require. The one I require is related to optical raytracing.

Answer (score 0):

`-e` means edit mode,
and it is optional that's why it is written in square brackets as `[-e]`.

If you want to edit the module as you use `pip install -e .` otherwise go for `pip install .`

Answer (score 0):

You need to type either

`pip install .`

or

`pip install -e .`

Comment: I used the following: pip install https://github.com/mess42/pyrate  Which gave the following    Collecting https://github.com/mess42/pyrate
  Downloading https://github.com/mess42/pyrate
     / 185 kB 1.6 MB/s
  ERROR: Cannot unpack file F:\temp\pip-unpack-qmo1b2mv\pyrate (downloaded from F:\temp\pip-req-build-rmffqoms, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of F:\temp\pip-req-build-rmffqoms